# VueJs: Responsive NavBar - 'ToggleButton' does not show elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, dom

I'm building a single page application in VueJs, and to this i would like to add a responsive NavBar.
Whatever i try and do, it simply dosen't work.

I've tried many solution, the closest i get to my goal is the following:

HTML

```
<template>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img style="width: 100px; border-radius: 50%;" src="../.." alt="Name here">
      <a href="/" class="nav-branding text-center">Name</a>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item custom-header-li">
          <RouterLink class="custom-header-menu-text" to="#">1</RouterLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item custom-header-li">
          <RouterLink class="custom-header-menu-text" to="#">2</RouterLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item custom-header-li">
          <RouterLink class="custom-header-menu-text" to="#">3</RouterLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item custom-header-li">
          <RouterLink class="custom-header-menu-text" to="#">4</RouterLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item custom-header-li">
          <RouterLink class="custom-header-menu-text" to="#">5</RouterLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>
```

CSS

```
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.custom-header-li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

.nav-branding {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #080808;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #080808;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #080808;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 70px;
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #080808;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }

  .nav-menu:active {
    left: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

JS

```
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
      const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

      hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
      navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried printing, and see that the class changes to 'active' and it does - even the icon changes view, but the list dosen't show up ?
Can anyone see what's wrong with the code?

I've also tried this solution for Vue: https://codepen.io/raphaelbensimon/pen/VGbLed (Excluded the loader/spinner)

Here the problem is that the 'ToggleIcon' just dosen't show up, at all!

Can someone please help? :D

Comment: there's a vuejs 4? - the only mention of `ToggleIcon` is in that one sentence, that it doesn't show up at all .... personally, I'm clueless as to what `ToggleIcon` even IS, let alone why it doesn't "show up" - I also can't understand why `addEventListener` or `document.querySelector` would **ever** appear in `vue.js` code!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, according to dependencies i got `"vue": "^3.2.37", "vue-router": "^4.0.16"`
The 'toggleicon' i mention is the icon for hamburger-menu.. About the addEventListener and querySelector, is what i found in other examples.

What else do you suggest to make a responsive NavBar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a change in your css to:

```
.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
}
```

It's work. [Testing](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2gw7zd/6/)

Comment: Ohh jesus, what a typo! i had it ".nav-menu:active" with instead of dot! :) Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you tell me, why my hamburger changes class to active, no matter where on the page i click ?

Comment: It's simple, follow the code:
  `window.addEventListener("click", function( ) )
  window -> element;
  addEventListener -> method of listener;
  click -> Type event listened;
  function -> callback;`
You did add your event linstener to window, you need to add in your element.
Like that:

      `hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          console.log('hamburger')
      })`
***Note:*** There are other ways to do this, you can use directives like @click to do this. That way you don't neet to use the listener.

Comment: Thx.. i changed to use @click instead ;)